# How to keep user authorized_keys files when creating instance from machine image from a different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two GCP projects A and B, and I have a machine image in B, the machine image was created from a original instance that has a group users(each user has the ~/.ssh/authorized_files in their home directory).

When I create a new instance in B using this machine image in B, all the users' authorized files got kept. But when I create a instance in A using the machine image in B, the authorized_keys were lost in the new instance, except me which is the owner of B.

The command I used is:

gcloud beta compute instances create new_instance --project=A --source-machine-image projects/B/global/machineImages/machine_image_name --service-account A's_service_account --network=vpc_network_in_A --subnet=subnet_in_A

What else I need to add to the command in order to get the users' authorized_files cross from B to A?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: I know that I can add users' public keys in the metadata on A so whenever there is a instance created in A, those users' authorized_keys file will be created from the metadata. I am just afraid that this will give those users' too much access in A. Ideally I want them to have access only to the instances created from the machine image...

Comment: Have you tried using [instance-level public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only) before creating the image on B?

Comment: no, I have not done that before and will try and let this thread know. Thanks for bring it to me.

Comment: I tested to use instance-level ssh key for the instance and then create the machine image out of the instance. The image preserved the user ssh key and the new instance created from the image has the user key. Thanks Alex G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on the question, you will need to use the setup for [Instance-level public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only) to achieve your use case of preserving the SSH information on the image. But take note that this also blocks, `project-wide public SSH keys` from the instance.

Just to summarize the steps for console on this post.

1. Go to VM Instance Page
2. Click the Instance to go to its details, then click Edit.
3. Under SSH Keys, click Show and edit. (This section expands to show all of the instance-level public SSH keys.)
4. Next is to modify the instance-level public SSH keys:
   Add a public SSH key into the text box then click Add item.
5. After adding the keys, Click Save

Comment: That's what I did and it worked as expected. Thanks @Alex